# While adding my project to GitHub, do I also have to add the virtual environment folder and subsequently commit and push it or I can skip it?

Tags: django, git, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I just finished with my project and was going to put it on GitHub but I have this doubt regarding the venv folder. Below is the screenshot of my folder-structure;

[image: Folder-structure]

Please guide me as this is my first time using GitHub and this is my first project too.

Comment: You should not be committing the virtual environment.  It will be huge ... and you should be able to regenerate it.

Comment: @StephenC So I should just commit accounting and requirements.txt, right?

Comment: @StephenC I'm sorry I didn't understand what you meant by 'and you should be able to regenerate it.'!

Comment: You should be able to regenerate the virtual environment the same way you created it in the first place.  Run `virtualenv` (or whatever) and then use `pip` (or whatever) to reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: Having said that ... you probably shouldn't have put the `venv` directory inside your project tree in the first place.

Comment: Might that be a problem for me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+virtual+environment+

Comment: Well ... it might cause you to accidentally commit the "venv" directory.  That would be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not commit the `venv` directory. The ones who will clone your git repository will be able to create their own virtual environment from scratch thanks to the `requirements.txt` file, which you should definitely keep up-to-date and commit into the git repository.

To install the required packages in a virtual environment:

```
path/to/venv/python -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt
```

***References***:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what seeding a virtual environment means? It'll be helpful.